# Wordpress: Open add_meta_box by choosing a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

How is it possible, to display my add_meta_box (in the WYSIWYG Editor - create new post page) only when the post is related to a specific category for example cat no. 5.

BR & Thanks,
mybecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've seen is using jQuery to hide or display meta boxes depending on category using this technique here on Stackexchange;

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14707/post-formats-how-to-switch-meta-boxes-when-changing-format

I dropped the Heredoc syntax but this solution works really well.